# jQuery Clone function with callback - not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

First, here is a JSfiddle with my work: http://jsfiddle.net/xzGxR/

**The JavaScript:**

```
function dataClonePrototype(JSOtarget, ElementPrototype, callback) {
    for (i = 0; i < JSOtarget.length; i++) {
        var TargetElement;
        if (!Eclone) { // Only create it on first interval
            TargetElement = $(ElementPrototype);
            var Eclone = TargetElement.clone(); // We only want to create a copy of this clone...
        } else {
            TargetElement = Eclone.clone().insertAfter(ElementPrototype);
        }
        callback(TargetElement, JSOtarget[i]);
    }
}

var returnedJSO = 
{
    "Animals": [
        {
            "Title": "Dogs",
            "Amount": 300
        },
        {
            "Title": "Pigs",
            "Amount": 230
        },
        {
            "Title": "Cats",
            "Amount": 340
        }
    ]
}

dataClonePrototype(returnedJSO.Animals, "section#animals", function(Element, JSOtargetAtKey) {
    Element.children("header").html(JSOtargetAtKey.Title);
    Element.children("article").html(JSOtargetAtKey.Amount);
});​
```

**And the HTML:**

```
<section id="animals">
     <header></header>
     <article></article>
</section>​
```

**The output should (visually) look like this:**

```
Dogs
300
Pigs
230
Cats
340
```

**Yet, it looks like this.**

```
Dogs
300
Cats
340
Pigs
230
Cats
340
```

The goal of this is to use the HTML and create clones of it - then populate these clones with data from the javascript object. It should populate like this:

```
<section id="animals">
   <header>Dogs</header>
   <article>300</article>
</section>​
```

Something is wrong with the code that clones, but I can't figure out what. Any advice/help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzGxR/1/)

```
function dataClonePrototype(JSOtarget, ElementPrototype, callback) {

    $TargetElement = $(ElementPrototype);
    for (i = 0; i < JSOtarget.length; i++) {

        var $Eclone = $TargetElement.clone(); // We only want to create a copy of this clone...

        callback($Eclone, JSOtarget[i], $TargetElement);
    }
}


dataClonePrototype(returnedJSO.Animals, "section#animals", function($Element, JSOtargetAtKey, $Prototype) {
    $Element.children("header").html(JSOtargetAtKey.Title);
    $Element.children("article").html(JSOtargetAtKey.Amount)
        $Element.insertAfter($Prototype);
});​
```

Comment: THANK YOU thank you thank you. I just wanted some advice but you solved my problem. Fantastic

Comment: no problem. I was pretty sure the error was happening because you were cloning the item and inserting it into the dom before you had made changes to it, but I wasnt certain until I played with it :)